# Какой знак препинания нужен перед словом "это"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> После насыщенного отдыха(?) это (?) было скучное время.

Comment: Полезность ответа здесь отмечают галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

**После насыщенного отдыха это  было скучное время.**

Здесь нет знаков препинания. Обстоятельство в начале предложения не обособляется, слово ***это*** является подлежащим

Comment: Спасибо большое! Скажите, а если бы был вариант : после насыщенного отдыха и быстрого полета это было скучно время и возможность погрустить

Comment: Знаков препинания тоже нет. Обстоятельство по-прежнему не обособляется (это детерминант, отнесенный ко всему предложению). Основа усложняется, теперь у нас однородные именные части сказуемого, но они связаны союзом И, поэтому нет запятой. Предикативная основа: это было время и возможность.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @Sharon, Как вы оцениваете стилистику этого предложения? Ср.: После понедельника это был вторник.

Comment: А если так: После насыщенного отдыха для меня это было скучное время.